# create javascript function to toggle sprite

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, sprite

I am working on creating a JS/jQuery function to toggle the position of an icon sprite.  So far I have gotten this code to work:

```
$('.toggle-completed').mouseup(function(){
var sp = ($(this).css('background-position'));
$(this).css('background-position', 
    sp = sp == '-82px 50%'? '-101px 50%' : '-82px 50%'
);
});
```

However I want to abstract this so that it can work with any sprite pair.  Something like this:

```
var toggleSprite = function(firstPosition, secondPosition){
var sp = ($(this).css('background-position'));
$(this).css('background-position',
    sp = sp == firstPosition ? secondPosition : firstPosition
);
};
```

Which would be called as follows:

```
toggleSprite('-82px 50%', '-101px 50%');
```

However this code generates an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 
'backgroundPosition' in undefined
```

I am thinking that either 1. I can't really use 'this' in a function.  Or perhaps I am not calling the function correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the is the `this` reference... it does not looks like to be referencing the target element.

I think you can write it as a simple plugin like

```
$.fn.toggleSprite = function (firstPosition, secondPosition) {
    return $(this).css('background-position',    function(idx, sp){
        return sp = sp == firstPosition ? secondPosition : firstPosition;
    });
};
```

then call it like

```
$(this).toggleSprite('pos1', 'pos2');//or $(el)
```

---

or pass the elements as a param to the method

```
var toggleSprite = function (els, firstPosition, secondPosition) {
    $(els).each(function () {
        var sp = $(this).css('background-position');
        $(this).css('background-position', sp = sp == firstPosition ? secondPosition : firstPosition);
    });
};
```

then

```
toggleSprite(myels, 'pos1', 'pos2')
```

---

A third option is to pass a custom context to the toggle method using [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
toggleSprite('-82px 50%', '-101px 50%').call(myel);
```

Comment: Good idea suggesting `call`, that may prove to be the simplest option for the OP

Comment: In the plugin example(first code block of your response) what is the purpose of function(idx,sp)  Which others suggested as function(_,sp).  Specifically what is the purpose of 'idx' or the '_'?

Comment: @dtburgess that is just any variable name... the callback function takes 2 arguments... 1) the index of the current item, 2) the current item... so we need to have 2 different parameters for the function.. we can name it anything we need

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a jQuery callback, `this` often refers to the DOM element that triggered the event, so can be used in a selector (`$(this)`), but in your example that creates an error, the context is a vanilla js function, so `this` refers to the current scope, not a DOM object.

Perhaps extend the jQuery `fn` object...

```
jQuery.fn.toggleSprite = function(firstPosition, secondPosition){
var sp = ($(this).css('background-position'));
$(this).css('background-position',
    sp = sp == firstPosition ? secondPosition : firstPosition
);
// also, return $(this) so that chaining is not broken...
return $(this);
};
```

And call like this...

```
$('.some.selector').toggleSprite('-82px 50%', '-101px 50%');
```

So that the function knows what `this` refers to.

Comment: thanks for the explanation regarding wrong context.  And, yes, this worked in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having has to do with the fact that the function context `this` is not bound to a specific DOM element when used in a generic (i.e. non-jQuery) function. One of the more powerful features of the jQuery library is that the function context `this` is bound to the DOM element that calls the jQuery function, allowing the user to easily target a specific element. In regular JavaScript, `this` refers to the current scope, which in your case is the function `toggleSprite`.

For your purposes, I think a simple jQuery plugin function would do the trick:

```
$.fn.toggleSprite = function(pos1, pos2) {
  return $(this).css('background-position', function(_, sp){
    return sp == pos1 ? pos2 : pos1;
  });
};
```

The benefit of this method is that you can then call this function on any jQuery object as you normally would:

```
$('.sprite').toggleSprite('-82px 50%', '-101px 50%');
```